# Creating a split view application similar to 'settings' app

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

I am trying to build an iPad app set-up as a split-view, but on the detail page being able to drill down like a navigation controller.

An example of this working is the setting app on the iPad where if you select the 'General' tab you can then drill down on the detail page from say general > network > VPN

Any help or tips on this would be great. I thought it might be two navigation controllers on the root nib, but couldn't get this working.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like General -> About ->.. (in ipad simulator) right .

if all your detail view needs the TableView, then its better to make your detailviewcontroller as  the subclass of UITableViewCOntroller.

OR If you need different views when click on the cells of rootcontroller(left pane)

Create a method in DetailViewController say setDetailView{}. And call this method when click on the cell of RootController
inside this method,

1. remove all subviews from detailview
2. create UITableView and set its delegates
3. on tableview didSelect method, we can push other UIViewController instance
   [self.navigationController push...]

Hope it helps.